# Position() is not starting from 1 in xslt

Tags: xslt

When i take position in xslt ,the value is starting with 5. But it should be start with "1". Is there any reason i am getting value 5 here. I am using the variable "tempPosition" to get the value of position. Since it is starting with 5 i am subtracting 4 to start from  1. But i would like to know why it is starting from 5..

Here is my xslt:

`<param name="Temp.response"/>`
 
    
  
 
  `<template match="mm:value[position() &lt;= 90]">`
 
    `<variable name="tempPosition" select="(position()-4)"/>
    <!-- Get node name of parent element -->
    <variable name="mm" select="local-name(..)"/>
    <Wed3Tierfff>
      <variable name="tempStrtDt"
                select="/mm:response/mm:data/mm:ffst/@starmmime"/>
      <fffStartDt>
        <value-of select="$tempStrtDt"/>
      </fffStartDt>
      <variable name="tempStrtDtHrs" select="substring($tempStrtDt,12,2)"/>
      <variable name="tempStrtDtFinalHrs"
                select="$tempPosition+$tempStrtDtHrs"/>
      <fffEffectDtHe>
        <choose>
          <when test="string-length($tempStrtFinalHrs) = 1">
            <variable name="tempfffEffectDtHe"
                      select="concat(substring($tempStrtDt,1,11),0,$tempStrtDtFinalHrs,substring($tempStrtDt,14,12))"/>
            <value-of select="$tempfffEffectDtHe"/>
          </when>
          <otherwise>
            <variable name="tempfffEffectDtHe"
                      select="concat(substring($tempStrtDt,1,11),$tempStrtDtFinalHrs,substring($tempStrtDt,14,12))"/>
            <value-of select="$tempfffEffectDtHe"/>
          </otherwise>
        </choose>
      </fffEffectDtHe>
    </Wed3Tierfff>
  </template>
  <!-- Match the "ffst" node and create the "TierCollection" node. Apply templates to children of the "ffst" node -->`
 
    
      
    
  ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to tell what position() should be within your template without seeing the apply-templates instruction that invokes it. If your apply-templates instruction selects 17 nodes, and template T matches the fifth of those nodes, then within template T the value of position() will be 5. You haven't said why you think it should be one, so I suspect you havent' understood the spec correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your response Michael.  This is the first template which i am using.. `<template match="@* | node()">
    <apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </template>`

Comment: Well, how many nodes does `select="@* | node()"` select? Without seeing your source XML, we can't tell. Certainly, it seems likely to select nodes that don't match this template as well as nodes which do, and position() is counting the number of nodes selected, not the number that this template matches.

Comment: Here is the source xml. <response> <data><cast castCode="MT=" startTime="2015-08-18T00:00:00-05:00"
          endTime="2015-08-24T23:00:00-05:00" frequency="3600"
          castProduct="week">
      <site>
        <Sname>Cc</Sname>
        <sc units="kW">55.0</sc>
        <sL latitude="43.715900" longitude="-88.302900"/>
      </site> <aT units="K" statistic="n50" name="mean">
      <!-- I am taking the postion here-->
        <value>99.639383952</value>
        <value>99.312591553</value>
    
      </aT>
    </cast>
  </data>
</response>

Answer (score 2):

You should post a *reproducible* example, preferably minimized to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem.

In general, the `position()` function returns the position of the current node **in the [current node list](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#dt-current-node-list)**. And the current node list is determined by the currently instantiated `xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:for-each` instruction's `select` expression - not by any template's `match` pattern.